# How to proceed to a partial replacement for matching regex?

Tags: regex

I have a text looking like this:
"some texts (blabla) before (1) some texts after (2) text (3) text (4) text"

I want to remove all the "(" only when this one is part of "(number)"  to get this:

"some texts (blabla) before **1)** some texts after **2)** text **3)** text **4)** text"

In bold the text getting  the requested change. Note that the part (blabla) must not be considered.

What would be the correct regex to proceed to those replacements?

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: C#, but Nick has already shared the correct regex. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your regex language supports lookaheads you can match a `(` followed by some number of digits and a closing `)` and replace the `(` with an empty string. Regex:

```regex
\((?=\d+\))
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/44BYdE/1/)

If it doesn't support lookaheads, you can capture the digits and closing `)` and then replace the match with that capture group:

```regex
\((\d+\))
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BGFvM6/1/)